# Obter valores através dos parâmetros do método get

Tags: asp.net-mvc, get

Tenho uma `action` que manda por parâmetros o `codCliente`:

```
//master/CadastrarEndereco?codigoCliente=1011
```

Como faço para obter esse esse valor `codigoCliente`em minha *controller* para que eu possa persistir o valor no BD?

Answer (score 3):

No seu método `CadastrarEndereco` você pode declarar o parâmetro `codigoCliente` da seguinte forma e usá-lo.

```
public ActionResult CadastrarEndereco(int codigoCliente){
    // codigoCliente preenchido aqui dentro
}
```

Você também pode acessar o objeto `Request` para obter os parâmetros enviados:

```
var codigoCliente = Request.QueryString["codigoCliente"];
```